# Apache Kafka: Send Messages to another Topic after a period of time

Tags: apache-kafka

I am new to Apache Kafka, so it might be that this is basic knowledge.
At the moment I try to figure out some possibilities and functions that Kafka offers me. And so I was wondering whether it is possible to move a message after a specified period of time to another topic.

Scenario:
Producer 1 writes Message (M1) into Topic 1 where Consumer 1 handles the messages.
After a period of time, let's say 1 hour, M1 is moved into Topic 2 to which the Consumer 2 is subscribed.

It is possible to do something like that with Kafka? I know that there is a way to delete a message after a period of time, but I don't know if there is a way to change to topic or catch the delete-action.

I thought about running a timer in a Producer, but with a huge amount of data, I think that this isn't possible anymore.

Thanks in advance

**EDIT:**
Thanks to @OneCricketeer i know, that my first assumption with the several producers wasn't that bad.
I know that the throughput with one Producer is really good and that one won't take the system down.
But I'm still concerend about the second producer.
In my imagination it is like the following sketchy image
[image: Sketchy example of the process]

When I take 30 messages per minute that would mean that I would habe 31 instances of producers. 1 that handles the messages asap and 30 others waiting for the timer to determinate so that they can work with their message.
Counting that up to an hour it would be round about 1800 instances. That is where I#m concerned about. Or is there a better way to handel this?

Comment: You'd queue the data with a timed producer, yes. What issues are you having with that?

Comment: I'm thinking about a system that deals about 30 messages per minute oder something like that. When I add for each a new object with a runtime over an hour I guess that this might kill the server over time

Comment: Only one way to find out. And if so, increase the heap space

Comment: So I assume that there is no other way?

Comment: We have Kafka producers that send far more than 30 messages a minute (maybe even above that per second). Producers already have an internal `batch.size` setting in bytes that limits/batches requests anyway, so killing the server from that alone will be unlikely

Comment: Thanks for that answer. I guess that i understand what you are trying to tell me, but I still see a problem with the amout of instances.  I added my (probably wrong) way of thinking to the question

Comment: Why would you be creating new Producer instances when one instance is thread-safe and can be used to send to multiple topics?

Comment: I need to wait for an hour ( for each message) and i don't see a way to do this in only one instance, since each massage needs  an own timer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution that might work for my case.
I accidentally stumbled over a Consumer-Methode which allows you to read messages based on Timestamp.
The methode is called offsetsForTimes and usable since the Version 0.10.

See [the Kafka API](https://kafka.apache.org/0110/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/KafkaConsumer.html) or the following  [post](https://medium.com/@werneckpaiva/how-to-seek-kafka-consumer-offsets-by-timestamp-de351ba35c61)  which I found researching  about that methode.

Maybe this is usefull for others so I decided to publish this.